# Crashlytics / Fabric distribution of Watch-enabled iOS-App?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I sure am missing something obvious here - but no matter where I looked I found nothing to aid me here so I'll give it a try:

I'm developing an (obj-c) app in which I have integrated the Fabric / Crashlytics framework and which I distribute to my testers via the fabulous Fabric-Site. That worked flawless for many, many versions.
Now I have added AppleWatch-compatibility to my app via integration of WatchKit. All works fine.

But distribution via Fabric to my beta-testers just won't work any more; The distributions site just states "You're all set for now. As soon as a new Build is ready..." and under "Previous Versions" all version including the WatchKit are marked as "Not Available". Older versions are available to install though...

I suspect something wrong with the included provisioning profiles - but all are set up as they should - f.e. all devices registered in all profiles, separate profiles for the watch app and the extension - and the archives are created without errors or warnings. They even pass the AppStore validation. But no luck in getting those versions to my beta-testers...

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you create AdHoc provision profiles for your extension and watchkitapp bundleIds and included them to workspace settings? We use HockeyApp distribution and it works. All installation files for watch are delivered through your main app on the device.

Comment: Jepp - all was setup as it should be. Turns out, the Fabric-service is not yet ready for watch-kit enabled apps as there currently is no way to add the AppleWatch-UDIDs to the portal an thus no way to distribute these apps. Bummer. Because it shows how much I rely on this great beta-testing-service. Apples own one - TestFlight - can not match it I think... BTW, the whole setup-process in Xcode is a royal PITA - with all the trap falls in certificates, provisioning profiles and so on... I can imagine better ways to have fun... ;-(

Comment: Any news now about a fabric integration on a watchOS app ?

Answer (score 4):

As at current date it continues to appear to be the case that WatchKit Apps and Extensions cannot be distribute by Fabric. The [Fabric Documentation](https://docs.fabric.io) does not refer to WatchKit, WatchOS or Apple Watch at all, and the current [only significant discussion of the question in the developer forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-watch-app-not-showing/56727), from about five months ago, states it was not possible at that time.

Comment: Which new account Twitter dev account holders don't have access to.