# Fabric won't let app run

Tags: xcode8, watchkit, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, mopub

Guys I keep getting this error after running my app! I have no idea why this just started to happen but I can't seem to get it to work now. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
WatchKit v3 app has disallowed Info.plist key: Fabric


    <key>Fabric</key>
<dict>
    <key>APIKey</key>
    <string>mykey</string>
    <key>Kits</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>MoPub</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric doesn't support Watch OS 3.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062496/crashlytics-fabric-distribution-of-watch-enabled-ios-app?rq=1) appears to suggest it isn't, and I couldn't find any changes to the documentation to suggest it is.